# How do I run REST API in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, rest, phpstorm, php-7

When I run this bat file I get running my REST API without any issues:

```
cd C:\directory
php -S localhost:8000 routing.php
```

But I wasn't able to run it from PhpStorm:

[image: settings]

[image: settings]

[image: end result doesn't work]

Comment: Your port for the php server is 8000, but you have localhost:63342 in PHPStorm.

Comment: @Devon, now I made it `-S routing.php` but nothing has changed.

Comment: You need to use **PHP Built-in Web Server** type of configuration for such stuff. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-php-built-in-web-server.html?search=built